# Non deterministic dice rolls

Tags: random

Are there any algorithms out there for non deterministic dice rolls?

For example, I'd like to make a small mini-game: Liars dice. But the biggest issue here is dice rolling. When the cups are turned the result of the dice should be determined by the game rather than physics (if I were using unity for example). How can I ensure that the model behind it provides random results acute to an actual dice role?

Comment: How can you know if the universe itself is non-deterministic?

Answer (score 5):

A computer is a deterministic machine, there is no way to get non-deterministic random numbers from a computer barring some extra source of non-deterministic random numbers (which no PC has).

Just use a bog-standard pseudo random number generator. It's more than close enough.

Comment: This statement is simply not true.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

Comment: @dementedhedgehog What isn't true about my statement? How many personal computers have you seen with a hardware random source? Most servers don't even have one.

Comment: The (which no PC has) part.  I'll grant you it's a little pedantic.. but it's quite the definitive statement you've made.

Comment: Just a little, considering hyperbole is a thing that exists =p. I don't believe there is even a standard API for that kind of thing. And the handful of people who have that in their PC don't really count as a market in any meaningful way

Comment: Yeah.. I was a bit harsh.  I come from  the gambling industry.. slot machines and all that, so I have a different perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Use random and seed with the time. Here is some C# code just as an example. Not tested so there might be missing some ";" or similar :).

```
using System;    

Random randomizer = new Random(); //Uses system clock as seed value so every run will give different number each run.
int diceResult = randomizer.Next(1,6);
```

Then you just use the diceResult to decide which side is up on the dice. In other words just simulate the dice role by random and then adjust the physical representation to match. The player cant see the physical dice any way during the "roll".